# JWPlayer with RMTP and HTML5 with Amazon CloudFront

Tags: java, html, jsp, amazon-web-services, jwplayer

I'm trying to use Amazon CloudFront to stream/download videos using jwplayer.

Firstly, my s3 bucket is: miemiebucket.s3.amazonaws.com, and I put in 2 videos, which are MOV and MP4 respectively.

Then I went to cloudfront and created two distributions, streaming and download, which are:

s2y3u5i4t1fkbz.cloudfront.net (streaming)
dkgitv33rxgy.cloudfront.net (downloading)

I went back to my jsp file and tried 3 different settings with the JWplayer

1. The one in the documentation:

   ```
   out.println("<div id=\"myElement\">Loading the player...</div>");
   out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   out.println("jwplayer(\"myElement\").setup({");
   out.println("file: \"http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-kNspJqnJ.mp4\",");
   out.println("});");
   out.println("</script>");
   ```

Which works exactly as expected

2. I figured out that this is a html player. Hence I switched the file:

   ```
   out.println("file: dkgitv33rxgy.cloudfront.net\someVideo.MOV",");
   ```

   however it cannot play
3. Then I tried RMTP:

   ```
   out.println("'file': 'rtmp://s2y3u5i4t1fkbz.cloudfront.net/someVideo.MOV',");
   ```

Both 2 and 3 has this error:

```
    Error loading player: No playable sources found
```

2 and 3 doesn't work, but 1 works, so I'm guessing there is a setting that is not properly configured with Amazon CloudFront? I used no restricted access so I wouldn't need to sign the URL. When I typed in:

```
    http://dkgitv33rxgy.cloudfront.net\someVideo.MOV
```

I could download the file when I initially set someVideo.MOV into public.

I also set the bucket as a public bucket to make sure there is no problem connecting it through the browser.

Very confused with jwplayer and CloudFront, had anyone had this problem before?

EDIT: Solution at: [Primary and Fallback (RMTP and HTML5) for JWPlayer 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096180/primary-and-fallback-rmtp-and-html5-for-jwplayer-6)

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are trying to run this?

Comment: I'm still testing this on localhost, didn't put it on a server yet

Comment: Well... Testing on localhost doesn't work, but putting it up on my server works. Very Strange...

Comment: Ah, sounds like a server setting issue on your local. Glad it works though.