# Fallback to direct download

Tags: jwplayer

In JwPlayer, How do I Fallback play mode to direct download?

My Scenario is `RTMP->HLS->Direct Download`

My current code:

```
            jwplayer("<?php echo $this->id?>").setup({

                    autostart: 'true' ,
                    flashplayer: "<?php echo CHtml::asset($this->_path.'/jwplayer.flash.swf')?>",
                    width:<?php echo $this->width?>,
                    height:<?php echo $this->height?>,
                    playlist: [{
                        sources: [
                        {
                           //Desktop: Use RTMP protocol and played by flash.
                            file: "<?php echo $this->rtmpPath;?>"
                        },
                        {
                            //Mobile: Use HLS protocol and played by HTML5
                            file: "<?php echo $this->hlsPath;?>",
                        },
{
                            //Direct Download
                             ??
                            file: "<?php echo $this->ddPath;?>",
                        },
                        ]
                    }],
                    primary:"html5",
                });
```

...............................................

Comment: I would change the primary variable from html5 to flash, that way the RTMP stream will be attempted first. If that does not work, please provide a link so we can take a look here, thanks.

Comment: @EthanLongTail I need some localization and the only part which I could translate is HTML 5 version so i make it primary. Currently RTMP is work fine, I need a direct link because some mobile device version doesn't support playing video through JwPlayer.

Comment: Hi @EthanLongTail, I found [this sample setting](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/trunk/fl5/js/test/examples/m3u8.html). Is `standard` mode still valid in JwPlayer 6.x ?

Comment: Oh, we don't support localization. That URL you provided is for JW5.